# Workbooks.OpenText doesn't take 'fieldinfo' parameter

Tags: vba, ms-office, parameter-passing, excel-2003

The following code demonstrates the problem which is stated in questions title.

Copy & paste it in a new Microsoft Excel 2003 workbook.

```
Sub mytest()
    mypath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()

    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=mypath, DataType:=xlDelimited, _ 
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _ 
        semicolon:=True, _ 
        fieldinfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2)), _ 
        Local:=True
End Sub
```

Execute the code. It will ask for an input file where you should use this semicolon-seperated [test.csv](http://ge.tt/2q7vwYE/v/0).  It creates a new workbook and imports all the data from test.csv to sheet1.

The picture below shows the result
[image]

But It should have shown a result like this
[image]

---

`fieldinfo:=Array(Array(1, 2), Array(2, 2), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 2))`
states that Excel should treat all imported data as text.  Unfortunately it doesn't.

- The two-dimensional array: [first number is the column number, second number stands for data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.opentext%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) where 2 stands for text
- I have to use the 'local'-parameter because I'm on a localized OS with a localized Office 2003
- The operating system is irrelevant since it happens on Windows XP and on Windows 7

Can someone show me how to use opentext and fieldinfo in the correct way?

I already know the work-around with QueryTables.Add(Connection[...].
But thats not a solution for my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you rename the extension from the input file from .csv to .txt the `fieldinfo` parameter works as designed.

Comment: Thanks much for this, I spent ages trying `workbooks.opentext` on a .csv file and got bad results until I renamed it to .txt.  Is this documented somewhere?  I can't see a reference to CSV in the relevant MSDN [library page](http://bit.ly/14uzq3z).  And is there a workaround if I'm not able to rename the file from .csv?

Comment: @a.out Yes, have a look at this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/527894/50173). I recommend you use *QueryTables*. Have a look at the example code